# Open terminal windows and execute custom commands in them?

Tags: linux, terminal, zsh, linux-mint, zshrc

I just figured out how I can open a new terminal and immediately send it commands. The command I'm using on Linux Mint is "mate-terminal -x zsh -c '(stuff here) ; exec /bin/zsh". But, I hit a wall in regards to calling functions and aliases defined in my .zshrc file. Instead it says "zsh:1: command not found: ".

Answer (score 2):

`.zshrc` file is only used for interactive shells, http://linux.die.net/man/1/zsh

> Then, if the shell is interactive, commands are read from `/etc/zshrc` and then `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`

There is `-i` option ("Force shell to be interactive.") which may help you, try:

```
mate-terminal -x zsh -c '(stuff here) ; exec /bin/zsh -i'
```

or if you have zshrc commands in stuff:

```
mate-terminal -x zsh -ci '(stuff here) ; exec /bin/zsh -i'
```